# Group of Order $p^2$ Isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm a bit lost on this problem:

> Show that a group of order $p^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

The only thing I can think of that may relate to this problem is Lagrange's Theorem, where the order of a subgroup divides the order of a group. But I'm not sure if I can even use that for this problem... Any help would be tremendously helpful. Thank you!

Comment: HINT: Assume it is abelian. Then the two cases you describe follow depending on existence or non-existence of an element of order $p^2$.  The next problem is to show that there are no non-abelian groups of order $p^2$.

Answer (score 7):

Using Lagrange's Theorem is a great idea. Note that it also tells you about the order of an *element* of $G$, since the element generates its own subgroup of $G$. It tells you that all orders of elements in $G$ must be one of the positive integer factors of $p^2$ (which you know, since $p$ is prime).

Hint 1: What if $G$ contains an element of order $p^2$?

Hint 2: If $G$ does not contain an element of order $p^2$, what is the order of the non-identity elements of $G$?

Hint 3: Take an element $x \in G$ where $x \neq e$. Then take $y \in G \setminus \langle x \rangle$. Can you draw any conclusions about $\langle x \rangle \times \langle y \rangle$?

Comment: Why would the direct product be related to the original group? That last parts needs an extra argument.

Comment: Yes, it does, but keep in mind this is only a hint; there is no need to disclose further steps until the OP shows continued interest in the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the set $Z(G) = \{a \in G: \forall h \in G, gh = hg\}$. $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$, and contains more then one element due to the conjugacy class equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class#Conjugacy_class_equation). Consider an element $a \in Z(G)$, $a \neq e$. By Lagrange's Theorem, $o(a)$ is either $p$ or $p^2$ ($o(a)$ is the order of $a$). If $o(a) = p^2$, then clearly $a$ generates $G$, so $G$ is cyclic and hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$. Now suppose $o(a) = p$. Let $H = \left<a\right>$, and consider some element $b \in G \backslash H$. If $b$ generates $G$ we are done as above, otherwise $o(b) = p$, and $\left<b\right>$ is disjoint from $H$ (apart from the identity element). Then for $0 \leq m,n < p$, the elements $a^nb^m$ are all distinct, but there are $p^2$ such elements, so every member in $G$ is of this form. Also, since $\left<a\right> \subset Z(G)$, we have $a^{n_1}b^{m_1}a^{n_2}b^{m_2} = a^{n_1}a^{n_2}b^{m_1}b^{m_2} = a^{n_1+n_2}b^{m_1+m_2}$. Thus, the map $a^nb^m \mapsto (n,m)$ is an isomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: This is missing an argument for the subgroups normalizing each other at the end, as otherwise the product need not be direct.

Comment: Thanks. The normality of $\left<a\right>$ seems to boil down to proving that $G$ has a nontrivial centre, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: It more or less boils down to applying the class equation (though it also follows from it having index the smallest prime dividing the order of the group, which can be shown to imply that the subgroup is normal as well).

Answer (score 1):

(Note $|G|=p^2\implies G$ is abelian, but I'd leave that out as a separate proof.)

Let $a\in G$.  By Lagrange's Theorem $\operatorname{ord}(a) = 1, p$ or $p^2$ .

1. $\operatorname{ord}(a) = 1\implies a = e.$
2. $\operatorname{ord}(a) = p$.  Let $H = \langle a\rangle$, which is a subgroup of $G$.

   $(G:H) = p^2/p = p\implies G/H = \langle Hb\rangle$ for $b\in G$ and $b\not\in H$.

   In other words,\begin{align*}
       G = & \, \{e, \\
       &\,\, a, a^2, \cdots, a^{p-1}, \\ 
       & \,\,b, b^2, \cdots, b^{p-1}, \\
       & \,\,ab, ab^2, \cdots, ab^{p-1}, a^2b,\cdots, a^{p-1}b^{p-1} \}
     \end{align*}

   Let $f: G\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $f(a^xb^y) = (x, y)$ for $(x, y)\in\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$.

   (a) $f$ is invertible, as $f^{-1}(x,y) = a^xb^y \implies f$ is a bijection.

   (b) $f(a^xb^y) = (x,y) = (x,0) + (0,y) = f(a^x) + f(b^y)\implies f$ is a homomorphism.

   Hence $\operatorname{ord}(a) = p\implies G\cong\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$.
3. $\operatorname{ord}(a) = p^2\implies G = \{e, a, a^2, \cdots, a^{p^2-1}\}$.

   Let $f: G\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ such that $f(a^x) = x$ for $x\in \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

   (a) $f$ is invertible, as $f^{-1}(x) = a^x \implies f$ is a bijection.

   (b) $f(a^xa^y) = f(a^{x+y}) = x+y = f(a^x) + f(a^y)\implies f$ is a homomorphism.

   Hence $\operatorname{ord}(a) = p^2\implies G\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

$\Box$

Comment: 1. You are answering a 3-year-old-question with no activity since October 2016; are youy actually adding anything? 2. Your case two introduces a $b$ that is never defined, and you never prove your list does not contain repeats. I mean, you *could* have a cyclic group of order $p^2$, picked an arbitrary element $a$, and just happen to have picked an element of order $p$. Then what you do in case 2 is just plain wrong. You *cannot* conclude **just** from the fact that you found an element of order $p$ that the group must be $C_p\times C_p$.

Comment: (Nor do you prove, for that matter, in case 2, that the group must be abelian...)

Comment: Case 2 is still wrong. Imagine that $G$ is really the cyclic group of order $9$, and you happen to take $a=x^3$ and $b=x^6$; then $a\neq b$, both of order $3$, but your “list” contains a heck of a lot of repeats and does not exhaust the group. And you **still** haven’t justified that $a$ and $b$ must commute, so your $f$ need not be a homomorphisms.

Comment: See the note at the top on the abelian part.  Case 2 should also be fixed.

Comment: But now you don’t know that your cases exhaust all possibilities, nor have you *proven* that your list in case 2 does not include repeats. So, no, it’s not fixed, and you are still not adding anything that was not said over three years.

Comment: Repeat (in the "list" in case 2) is not possible.  Suppose $a^xb^y = a^{x'} b^{y'}$ or $a^m = b^n$ for $0< m,n < p$ which is not possible since $\langle a\rangle\ne\langle b\rangle$.

Comment: You don't need to convince *me*: you need to provide a full proof in your argument. This is a poor answer to a question that already had a couple of good ones. You've added nothing but gaps and incomplete arguments. What was the point?

Comment: Updated to improve the completeness of the proof.